# Only import two columns from a CSV

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a CSV file with 20 columns and 100s of rows. I want to create an SQLite database using just two of the columns - the date in column 1 and temperature is column 10. I have modified some example code I found, but am not sure how to get it to just use these two columns.

```
import csv, sqlite3
import sys

filename = sys.argv[-1]

con = sqlite3.connect("my.db")
con.execute("create table stats(date, temperature)")                               
cur = con.cursor()

stats = csv.reader(open(filename))

con.executemany("insert into stats(date, temperature) values (?, ?)", stats)

con.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
con.executemany("insert into stats(date, temperature) values (?, ?)",
                ((rec[0], rec[9]) for rec in stats))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to *read only the specified columns* and write them to a `DB`

```
import sqlite3
from pandas.io import sql
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

s = """Year,Make,Model
1997,Ford,E350
2000,Mercury,Cougar"""

f = StringIO(s)
df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols = ['Year','Model']) # reads specified cols
                                                # to a DataFrame

con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
sql.write_frame(df, name='test', con=con)

print sql.read_frame('select * from test', con) # reads data back 
                                                # to DataFrame
```

out:

```
   Year   Model
0  1997    E350
1  2000  Cougar
```